# In Racket, if I invoke `lambda` with multiple body arguments, what happens?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda, racket

The [Racket Docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html) state that the `lambda` function can be invoked with multiple arguments after the `body` argument, e.g.:

```
((lambda () (display "foo") (display "bar")))
```

prints `foobar`.

How exactly does this work? I didn't find any explanation in the racket documentation. Did I miss something?

Comment: This is off topic for Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Adam What Q&A Site would you recommend?

Comment: Probably StackOverflow.SE. But let one of the moderators move it. That way it won't be tagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procedure bodies have an implicit `begin`. Thus

```
(lambda ()
  (foo)
  (bar))
```

is treated as if the same as

```
(lambda ()
  (begin
    (foo)
    (bar)))
```

See [Sequencing](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/begin.html) in the Racket guide for more details.